# Square error clustering for Texture Segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, k-means, image-segmentation

I am doing Texture Segmentation in Images Using Gabor Filters. I have generated Feature images and now i want to cluster them using square clustering or K-means.
Since i am working in MATLAB, I am using the matlab defined functions.
The official documentation for K-means clustering states

```
 idx = kmeans(X,k)
```

where,X= n by p data matrix and k is the number of clusters.
I want to know how to use this function for my dataset since i have n feature images  which means i have n features for every pixel of the original image. So my question is how do I use my dataset in the above function.
Also, if no function exists please explain how can I implement it on my own.

I am referring this research paper( page 6 )
[Gabor filters for texture Segmentation](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~visiope/Articoli/Texture/Gabor/jain97object.pdf)

Comment: how many "feature" images do you have, what is the dimension of each such image?

Comment: The number of feature images generated depends on the image width of the original image. For the sake of simplicity, lets assume thatt i have 20 feature images each having dimensions  188 * 268.